# use stringIO object as ssl key/cert file

Tags: python, python-3.x, twisted, stringio, twisted.internet

I want to pull my ssl certificate and key from environment variables and not store them on the filesystem.  But I am running into a road block with twisted ssl

```
from io import StringIO
from twisted.internet import reactor, task, threads, ssl

key = StringIO()
key.write(os.environ['SSLKEY'])
cert = StringIO()
cert.write(os.environ['SSLCERT'])

contextFactory = ssl.DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory(key, cert)
```

gives me the following exception

```
2018-04-03 16:01:28-0500 [-] TypeError: Path must be represented as bytes or unicode string
```

or

```
contextFactory = ssl.DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory(key.getvalue(), cert.getvalue())
```

gives me the following exception.

```
2018-04-03 16:02:44-0500 [-] OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('system library', 'fopen', 'File name too long'), ('BIO routines', 'file_ctrl', 'system lib'), ('SSL routines', 'SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file', 'system lib')]
```

twisted.internet.ssl is looking for a string or bytes object  of the filename and io.StringIO gives me a io.StringIO object.

Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twisted uses OpenSSL to actually implement TLS.  Twisted merely provides a wrapper around OpenSSL's APIs to make them easier to use.

The `DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory` initializer takes certificate and key filenames, not certificate and key themselves.  So, you cannot accomplish what you want with this API.

`twisted.internet.ssl.CertificateOptions`, however, will accept key and certificate objects to its initializer:

```
from os import environb
from twisted.internet.ssl import (
    CertificateOptions,
    PrivateCertificate,
)

cert = PrivateCertificate.loadPEM(
    environb['SSLKEY'] + b'\n' + environb['SSLCERT'],
)
key = cert.privateKey

contextFactory = CertificateOptions(
    privateKey=key.original,
    certificate=cert.original,
)
```

There is probably also a better way to load the certificates using the `cryptography` library (which will hopefully supplant a lot of `twisted.internet.ssl` key and certificate management APIs in the near future).

Also note that putting your private key into an environment variable in your process exposes it to *all other users and processes* on the same host.  This is a pretty bad idea (it's not very private, after all).  So you should probably put your key somewhere else.

Comment: I was not able to get this to work, however I am marking this as successful as this is a bad idea and I am instead storing these secrets as a file on the system instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `io.BytesIO` instead of `io.StringIO`

```
from io import BytesIO
key = BytesIO()
key.write(os.environ['SSLKEY'].encode())
```